# Revisted: What does $R(T^*)^{\perp}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, inner-products

---

A PLACE WHERE I ADD MY THOUGHTS AS I GO:

$$w\in R(T^H)^{\perp}:=\{v\in V ~:~ \langle v, T^Hv\rangle =0~\forall~w\in R(T^H)\}$$

$$\langle v , T^Hv \rangle = \langle ? , ? \rangle =0 $$

---

---

QUESTION:

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite diensional inner product space. Prove that $R(T^*)^{\perp}=N(T)$ and $R(T^*)=N(T)^{\perp}$.
$$\overset{?}{\downarrow}$$
Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite diensional inner product space. Prove that $R(T^H)^{\perp}=N(T)$ and $R(T^H)=N(T)^{\perp}$.
What does $R(T^H)^{\perp}$ mean? I've never seen the "$^{\perp}$" used that way.

---

---

$$\circ\circ\circ\circ~Data~\circ\circ\circ\circ$$

$$W^{\perp} := \{v\in V : \langle v,w\rangle=0 ~\forall~w\in W\}$$
$$R(T):=\{Tv~:~v\in V\}$$
$$N(T):=\{v\in V~:~Tv=0\}$$
$$T^H:=\bar{T}^{\top}$$

---

COMMENTS:

Is $T$ assumed to be left multiplication by $A$? That is, can I say $\bar{T}$ is the linear operator $\bar{T}:V\rightarrow W$, defined by $\bar{T}v=\bar{A}v$, where $\bar{A}=\bar{(a_{ij})}=(\bar{a}_{ij})$ and $A=(a_{ij})$? Is that what this thing is saying? Similarly, can I say $T^{\top}$ is the linear operator $T^{\top}:V\rightarrow W$, defined by $T^{\top}v=A^{\top}v$, where $A^{\top}=(a_{ji})$?

---

Comment: Orthogonal complement.

Comment: I know, but of the range of $T^*$. What does that mean?

Comment: Whoever deleted their answer. I wanted to at least read it before you deleted it.

Comment: $R$ for range, $T^*$ for the conjugate transpose of $T$ and $\perp$ for the orthogonal complement

Comment: Why the "Revisted [sic]" in the title? Does that mean you asked this question once before? And didn't link to it? Also, is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828919 helpful?

Answer (score 2):

This symbol is for the "orthogonal complement" of a subspace. In particular, you are asked to prove that the orthogonal complement of the range of $T^*$ is equal to the kernel of $T$, and that the range of $T^*$ is equal to the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $T$.

Comment: I see, so this proof will fall from the definitions of each, right?

Comment: @TyquanPesik Yes. And the definition of $T^*$.

Answer (score 1):

See Axler *Linear Algebra Done Right* P207 Theorem 7.7

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1712522)